# Is it possible to pass an ID to the app store when someone links to my app?

Tags: iphone, app-store, itunes, affiliate

We have different affiliates that sell our app and we want to know when an app purchase originates from one of our affiliates' websites.

So when someone clicks the link to our app is it possible to pass an ID that indicates which affiliate, and then attach that ID to the purchase transaction.

We want to give our affiliates a percentage of sales, so we need to know exactly which affiliate a purchase came from.

Comment: You may want to track that information using a reporting mechanism as proposed in this StackOverflow answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32022957/218152

Answer (score 2):

You can work with campaign links, check out the generator: https://analytics.itunes.apple.com/#/campaigngenerator

[image]

- id = the Apple ID of your app, will be the same
- pt = the provider
  token, will be the same
- ct = the campaign token, put here your different affiliates

After you get at least 5 installs from a campaign they start to show up in App Analytics. This it what you can expect it to look like:

[image]

You'll see:

- Impressions
- App Units (downloads)
- Sales
- Sessions (Opt-in data, so be careful)

https://developer.apple.com/app-store/user-acquisition-marketing/